# vim: gU and gu in one map

Tags: vim, dictionary, uppercase, lowercase

in vim, with

```
gUw
```

make the word uppercase, with

```
guw
```

make the word lowercase.
how I can convert in one map the upper to lower and the lower to upper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're trying to invert case, you can use `~`.  Normally this works only on the selection (e.g. visual mode), but if you want it to be more useful, then `:set tildeop` so you can do `~w` or whatever movement command you like.

Comment: Thats cool, I didn't know about that one. Unfortunately my brain is already well trained for tilde NOT to act like an operator. Guess I'll stay away from that command... :(

Comment: I always wondered why `~` didn't act like an operator.  Adding `tildeop`.  Thanks!

Comment: @dsummersi, I only discovered `~` recently, so why would you not want it to act like an operator?

Comment: @Brian because it works that way everywhere else. Like in readline, bash etc.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the tilde operator with global commands too: `g~w`

The advantage being, that you can then use the `.` operator to repeat the operation :)

Comment: in `g~w`, why `g`? `~w` is the same?

Comment: @JuanPablo `g~` forces `~` to act as an operator, even if you `set notildeop`.

Comment: This was new for me. And full of win. +1